# Obter Diretórios do Usuário (Windows)

Tags: dart

Existe alguma forma de obter os diretórios do sistema? No meu caso estou tentando obter a pasta `Download` do *usuário* logado

O máximo que consegui foi a pasta *temp* do usuario.

```
import 'dart:io';
main() {
  print(Directory.systemTemp.path);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Dart até aonde vi não tem meio de obter dinamicamente diretórios como:

- `/home/<usuario>/*` (geralmente linux)
- `/Users/<usuario>/*`
- `c:\Users\<usuario>\*`

Ao menos não com a classe [`Directory`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-io/Directory-class.html), infelizmente então o caminho é fazer isto manualmente, me baseando nesta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/25498458/1518921 ficaria algo como:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform, Directory;

void main() {
  String dir = "";

  Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;

  if (Platform.isMacOS) {
    dir = envVars['HOME'] + "/Downloads/";
  } else if (Platform.isLinux) {
    dir = envVars['HOME'] + "/Downloads/";
  } else if (Platform.isWindows) {
    dir = envVars['UserProfile'] + "/Downloads/";
  } else {
    throw "Sistema não suportado";
  }

  final downloads = new Directory(dir);

  downloads.exists().then((existe) {
    if (existe) {
      print("Downloads existe");
    } else {
      print("Downloads NÃO existe");
    }
  });
}
```

Mas vou ressaltar, existem outros sistemas como Solaris, BSDs (FreeBSD, OpenBSD, etc), iOS, Android, depende do que você vai fazer vai ter que ajustar manualmente, e outro detalhe importante, o usuário pode mudar a pastas padrões se configurar no sistema, exemplo em windows, exemplo no SuperUser:

- https://superuser.com/a/1126813/162728

Então esse código tem garantia minima de funcionar.